# How to integrate Powershell 7 with Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

How do I integrate Powershell 7 with Windows Explorer ?

I have installed Powershell 7 but it is not integrated with Windows (when I open default Powershell console  from `Windows Explorer` it starts with a version 5)

I learned that there should be a profile in the `users` folder, but it seems to be absent.

[image]

Comment: It also can be disabled.  It also has to be enabled by the user and is disabled by default.  It’s not clear why that particular feature is laugh out load funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell 7 ***(pwsh.exe)*** is not Windows PowerShell ***(powershell.exe and powershell_ise.exe)*** and does not replace or upgrade Windows PowerShell.

PowerShell 7 (***aka PowerShell Core***), is a cross-platform version solution. It is designed to run side-by-side with Windows PowerShell on Windows OS's.

It will never be the default since Windows PowerShell is delivered in the OS, thus the default and Powershell Core is a manual separate install. During the install of PowerShell Core, there were checkboxes that you should have selected.

- C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell
- ***C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\PowerShell***

Each having their own separate folder tree, profiles, settings, etc. Just as you had to first create a profile to get the folder tree in Windows PowerShell, you have to do the same for PowerShell core.

Just open ...

- Windows PowerShell (powershell.exe)
- Windows PowerShell ISE (powershell_ise.exe)
- PowerShell Core (pwsh.exe)

... and create a new profile in each instance.

```
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $Profile -Force
```

PowerShell Core does not, yet, completely provide all the Windows PowerShell does, and Windows PowerShell does not provide all that PowerShell Core does.

Use the right tool for your goals, but know your legacy PowerShell code can and will break on PowerShell Core. You will have to refactor those. As well as certain settings in your profiles that will fail.

If you want to use PowerShell Core  all the time, then there are several ways to make that happen:

1. Hit the Windows Key and type PowerShell and click the PowerShell version you want.
2. Hit the WindowsKey + R to start the run box and type pwsh.
3. Set a shortcut on your taskbar for pwsh.exe that you will use all
   the time.
4. Use the new Windows Terminal and set pwsh.exe and your default terminal.
5. If you are saying you are you want PowerShell 7 to be the RightClick
   run with, that means hacking the registry, or just create a shortcut
   to pwsh.exe and add that to your SendTo folder for use with
   Right-Click SendTo.
6. If you are saying, you want to right-click the Windows Key to get to
   the Advance menu (WinX) to select PowerShell, you have to hack that menu
   area as well.

References:

> ['add powershell 7 to explorer right click menu'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27add%20powershell%207%20to%20explorer%20right%20click%20menu%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27add%20powershell%207%20to%20explorer%20right%20click%20menu%27&sc=0-47&sk=&cvid=FAA603231B95445C9D177A1C2EA70C4C)
>
> ['modify the windows 10 win x menu'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=modify%20the%20windows%2010%20win%20x%20menu&form=ANNTH1&refig=c367f07908334f4899201cdf2ab69be0&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=modify%20the%20windows%2010%20win%20x%20menu&sc=1-32&qs=n&sk=&cvid=c367f07908334f4899201cdf2ab69be0)
>
> [Editing Windows Terminal JSON Settings](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/doc/user-docs/UsingJsonSettings.md)
>
> [Profiles.json Documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/doc/cascadia/SettingsSchema.md)

Comment: I wouldn’t say it will never be the default.  The next versions of PowerShell Core and .NET Core are the next versions of the respective projects.  Microsoft announced that over a year ago.

Comment: MS has also stated that though WPS is not getting any more work, they said it's not going anywhere and will be in the OS for the foreseeable future, just like cmd.exe has been for decades.Though what you re saying is a valid statement that does not equate to making it the OS default. Full .Net will be in the OS, too much still is dependant on it as well as the MS full-stack development environment, Visual Studio, as does core services, Exchange, SharePoint, Teams, SQL, et al. As per items via MSIgnite 2019. Yep, but, 'Never say never', I get that. Can we say MS and Linux/Android, etc.